# How can i get the path of file?

Tags: html, ruby

```
:image => StorageRoom::Image.new_with_filename(path)
```

I have to get the path of the image. So far i have specified the path manually and it worked and now i have put in heroku but it shows Load Error - No such file present. 
How can i get the path value of the local system using browse button.

Comment: `How can i get the path value of the local system using browse button.` Does this mean path value of file in user's browser?

Comment: yes.I want from users browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem may not be related to path names, but to the fact that Heroku has a read-only file system. If you try to write files onto disk in a Heroku app, it simply doesn't work -- the file will not be saved.

The exception is the "temp" directory. You *can* save files there, but they are not guaranteed to persist for longer than the duration of a single request.

Is the file you are trying to open actually saved in your Git repo? If so, it will be on the disk in your Heroku app, and you should be able to open it.

To see what the filesystem layout looks like on your Heroku instance, you can create a controller method like:

```
render :inline => Dir['**/*'].inspect
```

Comment: No actually the file is not present in git repo. I want to get from users browser

Answer (score 0):

```
File.expand_path
```

Reference : http://saaridev.blogspot.com/2006/11/ruby-finding-absolute-path-of-running.html

Comment: Actually i have put my file in server and when i run that it looks for file in that machine. But what i wanted is, it has to search in the machine where it is called.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the full path. As far as file path in the client machine is concerned for file uploads, the path is irrelevant as it poses **security risks** for the user.

Most modern browsers don't send the file path for file uploads. You could get the path using Javascript or Flash but still I don't see the logic behind doing this.

When a user clicks on the submit button the browser should at least send you the file name with the file data together with a bunch of other information like the mime type. Your web server would either write the file to disk or process it in memory assuming you have near infinite memory resources. Look at the [RFC 1867](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt) for file uploads for more on this.

Comment: Now i can tell you clearly. Consider a yahoomail where we can put some attachments. It gets file from user system and save it in mail. Similarly my ruby code is located in remote server and i want it to take the file from user system and save it in temp directory of the server.